# Log restful endpoints on container startup in a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, restful-url

I've a Spring application that expose restful endpoints through @RequestMapping annotation in Controller classes.

I wish that were logged into the console, at server startup, all the endpoints of all the application's controller.

I use a tomcat server and log4j for logging.

Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

**For those who use spring-boot:**

In the latest **spring-boot** release (since v2.1), they changed the mapping default log level (as specified in the Release Notes [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#logging-refinements)).

Add one of the following properties to **application.properties** file:

- `logging.level.web=TRACE`
- `logging.level.org.springframework.web=TRACE`

**Sample Console Output:**

```
2018-12-12 11:16:51.793 TRACE 11868 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
    c.n.c.MyController:
    {POST /users}: addUser(User)
    {DELETE /users}: deleteUser(User)
    {PUT /users}: updateUser(User)
    {GET /users/{id}}: getUserById(String)
    {GET /users}: getUsers()
    {GET /users_static}: getUsersStaticList()
2018-12-12 11:16:51.795 TRACE 11868 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
    o.s.b.a.w.s.e.BasicErrorController:
    { /error}: error(HttpServletRequest)
    { /error, produces [text/html]}: errorHtml(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse)
```

Comment: Actually none properties worked for me with Spring Boot 2.1.4. Only after I added this line to my logback.xml I saw my endpoints in the console: <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="trace" />

Comment: While this works, be careful as it will log a lot more stuff on TRACE also at runtime - what you probably do not want in a productive system. For me the tip with the actuator mapping endpoint below was what I actually needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40621584/1326662

Answer (score 9):

In log4J, add the info log level for 
`org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping` class.

With the level `INFO` :

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping=INFO
```

You should have this kind of information (lines are truncated):

```
2016-11-15 23:34:30.040  INFO 10156 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/contacts/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" o
2016-11-15 23:34:30.040  INFO 10156 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/contacts/{id}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/json]}
2016-11-15 23:34:30.040  INFO 10156 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/contacts],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produce
2016-11-15 23:34:30.040  INFO 10156 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/contacts/{id}],methods=[PUT],consumes=[application/json],pro
2016-11-15 23:34:30.040  INFO 10156 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/contacts],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto p
2016-11-15 23:34:30.040  INFO 10156 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/contacts/search],methods=[GET],params=[group-id],produces=[a
```

**UPDATE**

Since Spring MVC 5.1/Spring Boot 2, the logging strategy has changed.
Now very few information are logged with the `INFO` level, the `DEBUG` level provides more information but it is not detailed.
Only the `TRACE` level will provide detail information.

Here is the [changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What's-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x) (emphasis is mine) :

> Logging revision:
>
> Spring's JCL bridge can be detected by standard Commons Logging.
>
> **Less noise on info, readable debug logs, details at trace level**.

So change the logging configuration in this way to list all mappings :

Log4J properties way :

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping=TRACE
```

Logback way :

```
<logger level="TRACE" name="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>
```

Comment: it works however it also causes further log pollution by any request in the application.
"RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to ..."

Comment: reported an issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26539

Comment: Since Spring 5.3.5: solved. The solution is posted as the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66763885/1429367

Answer (score 6):

To add to the previous answer in `Spring Boot` there is the [Actuator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-enabling.html) that among other things is exposing a dedicated [Endpoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) called `mappings` accessible under `/mappings`.

Answer (score 6):

Since Spring 5.3.5, it's possible to use a special dedicated hidden Logger for logging the endpoints mapping, without overhead of logging all requests processing.

```
<Logger name="_org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.Mappings" level="debug" additivity = "false">
```

This feature was introduced in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26539

Comment: Is there any hidden logger also for servlet mappings and filter mappings?  Older Spring versions log these mappings at info level (from `ServletRegistrationBean` and `FilterRegistrationBean`).

Comment: @Pino as far as I could search by the query https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/search?q=getHiddenLog - no.

Maybe deeper checking of Spring framework code or documentation could help finding those