# spring boot 2.x console log does not print mapped controller info

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I can access the controller in web browser, but I can't see its mapping message in the console log. Normally when spring boot app starts, the eclipse console should print out the mapped controller and the accessing url, why didn't I see it?

I have already added the `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` to application.properties file, but it does not help.

**Updated:**
This is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.yp</groupId>
<artifactId>BootTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>BootTest</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[The snippet of console log when app starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiGvd.png)

Is there any way to show up mapped controller info when app starts?

Comment: Can you update the code? And what logging you like to seen in console? Spring boot does not log mapping urls to controllers unless you specify log message in method

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot 2.1? It uses Spring Framework 5.1 which includes a fairly major overhaul of Spring MVC’s logging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please view [Spring Boot 2.1 Release Notes#logging-refinements](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#logging-refinements)

> Spring Framework 5.1 revisited the debug logging output while working on web applications (Spring MVC or Spring WebFlux). If you are trying to debug an application and you want to restore Spring Boot 2.0 style logging you should add the following to your application.properties:

`logging.level.web=debug`

> You might also want to set `spring.http.log-request-details` to true to log actual request details. By default this property is false as it can potentially expose sensitive information.

Comment: This was (potentially useful to me) I didn't know about getting these logging details. I am on Bootstrap 4.0 using mvn from the command line to bring up a server instance. I found that I also needed to add:
 -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--logging.level.<your own packages>,spring.http.log-request-details=<Level>
to my command line ... not sure if it's going to solve my specific issue??

Comment: I may be wrong about the =<level> after the log.request.details, didn't seem to get much output other wise??

Comment: For much more logging use logging.level.root=DEBUG

Answer (score 1):

Just add this `-Ddebug` in the eclipse VM arguments and the detailed debug logs will start printing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Andy Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) there has been a lot of overhaul especially in terms of logging. The [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/28a5c3009ea0c31f879c0bb8b9e6cfd33faa81e5#diff-b91ebdcf6fba7c4886849e8144a7e687L546) removed the log.

If you wish to see this information, you can change the logging level to **TRACE** instead of falling back to a previous version

**`logging.level.org.springframework.web: TRACE`**

Comment: You can also use: logging.level.web=TRACE as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739836/6792588

Answer (score 0):

Just like the comment post by Andy Wilkinson said, I was using spring boot 2.1, when I change the spring boot version to older one, this issue doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

If only want to see controller mapping log. Try to set TRACE to RequestMappingHandlerMapping to prevent too much log.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping=TRACE
```

# spring boot 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

I like this answer and I think that' what I want.
Just see what apis is there while the application is running.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping=TRACE
```

and then you will see like this;

```
c.u.c.s.c.SmsAuthController:
    {POST /api/sms/send-sms-auth-code}: sendSmsAuthCode(SmsCodeParam,HttpServletRequest)
2568 2020-10-08 22:09:41,227 TRACE [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping/detectHandlerMethods  
    c.u.c.t.TestController:
    {POST /api/test/api-retired-warning}: testApiRetiredWithWarning()
    {POST /api/test/api-retired-error}: testApiRetiredWithError()
    {POST /api/test/api-test-only}: testApiTestOnly()、
2569 2020-10-08 22:09:41,228 TRACE [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.m.m.a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see info logs in eclipse just add following line to properties
**bootstrap.yml**

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

For much more logging, use `logging.level.root=DEBUG` in either bootstrap / application properties file